# boxes adding up to 100% of the browser

Tags: css

I want to have 2 boxes right next to each other, one with a fixed width, and another with a width that will change based on the size of the browser. The box has overflow:auto, and I'm trying to get the first box to act as a side bar that will follow you down the page. But of course I can't seem to achieve this, and have come here hoping someone could give me some examples, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want 100% height, or width?

Comment: Can you put your HTML and CSS up on jsfiddle so we can all have a play?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the layout you asked try something along these lines:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="col1">Left Navigation Menu</div>
    <div id="col2">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#col1
{
    position:fixed;
    width:400px;
}

#col2
{
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
}
```

Comment: @Dan Nice demo! However, is the width:auto style on #col2 necessary?

Comment: possibly not. I initially put that in but in hindsight don't think it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Will I was trying to think of a good way to do this in CSS, I was channeling my google-fu and found...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jStickyScroll

"This plug-in allows you to keep a div element at the top of the browser window when scrolling down a page. The most common use is to keep a sidebar navigation menu from disappearing when scrolling to the bottom of a web page."

You could maybe try...

```
#element{
   position:fixed;
}
```

Although this doesn't work without hacks in IE6, see
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go (I hope this is what you are after?):

See a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VcecU/

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_container">
        <div class="content_a">1</div>
        <div class="content_lotsoftext">Start. Lots of text goes here! Finish. </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_container{
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow:auto;
    zoom:1;
}

.content_a{
    width:60px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#3FF;
}

.content_lotsoftext{
    float:left;
    background-color:#FCF;
    margin:-20px 0 0 60px; /* -- Need conditional for IE6 and 7 to remove the margin to get it to work in those browsers --*/
    /*-- The following classes help it to sit better in IE6 and 7 --*/
    clear:left;
    display:inline;
}
```

Please note, you will need a IE6&7 conditional to remove the margin, clear and display classes from `.content_lotsoftext`